# How can I find action update post in Wordpress Admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im kinda new with wordpress. I wonder where is the code excute the action Update when I hit the button "Update" in wP admin when I edit post ?
Because I want to modify some information before it update to DB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to know where the code is located, Wordpress provides hooks for almost every action we do.

So in your case, when a post is updated there are some hooks that are fired.

1. **pre_post_update** Fires immediately before an existing post is updated in the database.

2.**transition_post_status** Fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another.

The 1st one

```
do_action( 'pre_post_update', int $post_ID, array $data )
```

You can run the `pre_post_update` hook and do whatever you need to do on the post.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated

Comment: Thank you man, but I just want to know when you click Update, what file in wp-admin will be excute ?

Comment: The file is `wp-includes/post.php` @DanielStark